# Why does Subject<T>.Dispose does not dispose current subscriptions?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Hi I've been thinking for some time that `Subject<T>` disposes all the subscriptions based on it if you manually call its `Dispose` method. But I've recently found it doesn't work that way, it just clears its inner collection of observers and substitutes it with a DisposedObserver helper class instance.

I found myself a little confused about the behaviour, just assumed that the "normal" would be just propagate and dispose all the suscribers. Later, trying to figure out why is designed this way, I guessed a couple of reasons why they designed this way.

- The suscriber may be a composition that depents partially on the subject , so full propagation of disposal doesn't make sense.  ie. Merge is not disposed just because one of the sources was disposed, as everyone expects.
- `Subject.Dispose` It is semantically equivalent to a continuation with `Observable.Never` from the side of the observer. The Subject.Dispose caller can also call OnComplete or OnError if wanted to signal error or completion before disposal (because they are on the same scope).

Edit Note:
Sorry for the unclear question. I already understand how to use it, this was more a design question. Let me state it more clearly.

Why do you think the designers of Rx made Dispose behaviour that way?

(the two points above are my answer trial)

Comment: You should add your answers as an answer rather than put them in the question.

Comment: The more interesting question (for me at least) is why they even made a Subject `IDisposable`.

Comment: It's a good question - as far as I can tell, Rx itself makes no use of it.

Comment: It looks like a big off switch - the Dispose call swaps the internal reference to Observers for a special DisposedObserver that makes further OnXXX calls a NOP and it causes an ObjectDisposed reference to be thrown to subsequent callers of Subscribe - I can see that being useful if you want to prevent any further Subscribers to a sequence.

Comment: ObjectDisposed *exception* I mean...

Comment: Disposing a Subject it's like when you clear the backing delegate of an event. I guess it's useful to stop holding references to observers  in the subject after a Complete or Error so you prevent possible leaks if the only retainer is the subject.                                And yes, the only call to Subject.Dispose I find in Rx sources are under Subject tests, and the check just verifies that it throws the object disposed exceptions when appropriate, not even them use it.

Answer (score 7):

A subject should indicate it is done by sending OnComplete or possibly OnError. This is idiomatically and grammatically correct Rx. Subscribers are responsible for ending their subscriptions by disposing them. You should write Observables such that they clean up resources once they are "done" even if subscribers have not unsubscribed.