# Turning a method call into an observable event, good idea?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm learning how to incorporate `IObservable` into my code. Below are two different approaches for a simple class that prints out the most recent word from an `IObservable<string>`. Which is the cleaner approach? I don't like `WordPrinterWithCache` because it introduces additional state (the `_lastWord`) variable and the interesting code is now scattered throughout the class. I prefer `WordPrinterWithExtraSubject` because the interesting code is localized to the constructor. But mostly it seems more consistently functional and "reactive"; I am reacting to the combination of two "events": (1) a new word being emitted, and (2) the invocation of the `PrintMostRecent` method.

However I have read that using Subjects is not desirable when it is not strictly necessary and I am introducing an unnecessary `Subject<Unit>`. Essentially what I'm doing here is generating an observable from a method call so I can use the observable combinator functions in more places. I like the idea of building up my code using the observable combinators and subscriptions rather than using "old-style" method invocation trees. I don't know if this is a good idea.

```
public class WordPrinterWithCache
{
    string _lastWord = string.Empty;

    public WordPrinterWithCache(IObservable<string> words)
    {
        words.Subscribe(w => _lastWord = w);
    }

    public void PrintMostRecent() => Console.WriteLine(_lastWord);
}

public class WordPrinterWithExtraSubject
{
    Subject<Unit> _printRequest = new Subject<Unit>();

    public WordPrinterWithExtraSubject(IObservable<string> words)
    {
        _printRequest
            .WithLatestFrom(words.StartWith(string.Empty), (_, w) => w)
            .Subscribe(w => Console.WriteLine(w));
    }

    public void PrintMostRecent() => _printRequest.OnNext(Unit.Default);
}
```

The actual scenario in my code is that I have an `ICommand`. When the user invokes the command (maybe by clicking a button), I want to take action on the **most recent value** of a specific observable. For example, maybe the `ICommand` represents `Delete` and I want to delete the selected item in a list that is represented by an `IObservable<Guid>`. It gets ugly to keep a bunch of "last emitted value" cache variables for each observable.

The approach I'm leaning toward is an `ICommand` implementation kind of like what you see below. This allows me to write code like `deleteCommand.WithLatestFrom(selectedItems,(d,s)=>s).Subscribe(selected=>delete(selected));`

```
public class ObservableCommand : ICommand, IObservable<object>
{
    bool _mostRecentCanExecute = true;
    Subject<object> _executeRequested = new Subject<object>();

    public ObservableCommand(IObservable<bool> canExecute)
    {
        canExecute.Subscribe(c => _mostRecentCanExecute = c);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged; // not implemented yet

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _mostRecentCanExecute;

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _executeRequested.OnNext(parameter);

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<object> observer) => _executeRequested.Subscribe(observer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure I'd use the term "turning a method call into an observable event", I have been a fan of using fully declarative, functional and Rx driven code for a while now.

Your description of an ICommand implementation matches very closely with one I wrote a couple of years ago and have used many times and very successfully since. Furthermore, this has become the basis for a pattern I refer to as "Reactive Behaviors" which provides numerous benefits. From my blog:

> - Promotes behavior driven development and unit testing.
> - Promotes functional and thread safe programming practises.
> - Reduces the risk of (and if done well, can eliminate) side effects as specific behaviors are isolated in a single well named method.
> - Stops 'code rot' as all behavior is encapsulated within specifically named methods. Want new behaviour? Add a new method. Don't want a specific behavior anymore? Just removed it. Want a specific behavior to change? Change the one method and know that you haven't broken anything else.
> - Provides concise mechanisms for aggregating multiple inputs and promotes asynchronous processes to first-class status.
> - Reduces the need for utility classes as data can be passed through the pipeline as strongly typed anonymous classes.
> - Prevents memory leaks as all behaviors return a disposable that when disposed removes all subscriptions and disposed all managed resources.

You can read the full article [on my blog](http://ian.bebbs.co.uk/posts/ReactiveBehaviors).

Comment: I've building my own reactive MVVM framework to see if I can arrive at the nirvana of super-simple declarative code. The approach on your blog is pretty awesome. It differs from what I've got in a few ways. (1) I expose the ObservableProperty<T> directly to the View as a read-only property and then bind to its Value property - less code. (2) My command takes an IObservable<bool> to define if enabled - more declarative. (3) Using one method per behavior is a really cool idea; my constructor has gotten way too big and though functional, is spaghetti.

Comment: Hi Justin, glad you found the blog post informative. Couple of questions about your comments: (1) Does your ObservableProperty implement INotifyPropertyChange? (2) My command is an IObserver<bool> rather than taking an IObservable<bool> as a constructor parameter and having an (internal and potentially leaky) subscription to the observable. (3) I tend to put the behaviour declaration in an Initialize call rather than the constructor but this was just an example. Good luck with your framework!

Comment: Oh, also, I'd recommend aiming to write a 'library' rather than a 'framework'. Great post on the subject (and difference!) here: http://tomasp.net/blog/2015/library-frameworks/
Just something to be think about while you're architecting...

Comment: Yes my property does INotify, My command has internal subscription, but I'm not too worried about leakiness since garbage collector cleans it all eventually. I noticed your command and property hold a Subject, but do NOT dispose; not sure this is ok. Very much like how you structured your app sample. I think the idea is that a "behavior" is something that has a side-effect, like changing state, and these are implemented by subscriptions. I'll keep trying to do it my way and then compare to how you've done it.

Comment: When I dispose the command and property, I first send OnCompleted through the internal subjects. I read somewhere that doing that eliminates the need for subscribers to dispose of subscriptions.

Comment: Justin, as per Lee's answer below and these posts ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323087/should-i-be-calling-dispose-on-reactive-extensions-rx-subjectt), [2]()http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540853/why-does-subjectt-dispose-does-not-dispose-current-suscriptions) the general recommendation is to manage subscription lifetime, not Subject lifetime (i.e. dispose the subscription not the subject). This is certainly the approach I have taken with regards to my command being an IObserver<bool> rather than maintaining an internal subscription.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm spending hours trying out your approach of "behaviors" and using a command that is an IObserver rather than using an internal subscription. So far it seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

So as a general rule (guideline), I strongly suggest not having an `IObservable<T>` as a parameter to a method. The obvious caveat being if that method is a new Rx Operator e.g. `Select`, `MySpecialBuffer`, `Debounce` etc.

The theory here is that `IObservable<T>` is a callback mechanism. It allows something to callback to another thing that it otherwise knows nothing about. However in this case, you have something that knows about both the `IObservable<T>` (parameter) and the other thing (`WordPrinterWithCache`). 
So why is there this extra layer of indirection? What ever it was that was pushing values to the `IObservable<T>` could just instead call a method of the `WordPrinterWithCache` instance.

In this case, just call a method on the other thing

```
public class WordPrinterWithCache
{
    private string _lastWord = string.Empty;

    public void SetLastWord(string word)
    {
        _lastWord = word;
    }

    public void PrintMostRecent() => Console.WriteLine(_lastWord);
}
```

Now this class starts to look rather pointless, but that might be ok. Simple is good.

Use Rx to help you with layering.

Upstream layers depend on down stream layers. They will directly call methods (issue commands) on the downstream layers.

Downstream layers wont have access to upstream layers. So to expose data to them they can either return values from methods, or can expose callbacks. The GoF Observer patter, .NET Events and Rx are ways to provide callbacks to upstream layers.

Comment: My question was Method(int x) { do_y } is similar to having an IObservable<int> to which you Subscribe(x=> { do_y }). rx functions are good for complex conditions like if a b and c happen, do_something. In my example, Subject<Unit> is a way to make something happen using the same rx functions. Both work - not sure which is better.

Comment: My ICommand takes an IObservable<bool> to control whether the command is enabled or not. I like this since when I define the command I declaratively indicate whether it is enabled or not. I think you are recommending an approach where some code outside the command subscribe to an IObservable<bool> and sets the CanExecute state by calling a method on the command, or maybe make the command an IObserver<bool>. Both work. I need to think about your layering argument; don't grok it yet.

Comment: I think what you mean by layering, is this - the time to define events is when you don't really know who your consumers are. if you know who your consumers are, don't bother raising an event just to have it passed along to its intended recipient. same goes for using iobservable; if you know who is listening, send the message directly to them.

Comment: Consider type A references type B. A communicates to B by executing methods on B. However B doesn't know about A, so if B needs to get data to A, then A needs to enlist in some sort of call back.

Comment: Lee I'd love to get your feedback on this question. I've been trying to follow your advice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569678/passing-an-iobservable-to-a-constructor-good-idea